# Reply bot for reddit. Simple bot that replies when "doctor" is mentioned

Tags: python, reddit

My bot is fully functional and I would love some feedback. Thanks!

Main loop for keep it running (main.py)

```
from functions import RunBot, InitPraw

reddit_handler = InitPraw()
doctor_who_subreddit_handler = reddit_handler.subreddit("doctorwho")

while(True):
  RunBot(doctor_who_subreddit_handler)
```

Functions that make it work (functions.py)

```
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep
from praw import Reddit
from os import environ
from random import randint
import pytz
from sys import stderr

def InitPraw():
  return Reddit(
    client_id = environ['CLIENT_ID'],
    client_secret = environ['CLIENT_SECRET'],
    user_agent="console:doctor-who-bot:v1.0.0 (by u/doctor-who-bot)",
    username = "doctor-who-bot",
    password = environ['PASSWORD']
  )

def LoadQuotes():
  quotes = []
  file = open('quotes.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
  for line in file:
    quotes.append(line)
  file.close()
  return quotes

def AlreadyReplied(replies):
  for reply in replies:
    if reply.author == "doctor-who-bot":
      return True
  return False

def GetRandomPositionOfObject(object):
  return randint(0, len(object)-1)

def ReplyRandomQuote(comment):
  quotes = LoadQuotes()
  random_quote_position = GetRandomPositionOfObject(quotes)
  reply = quotes[random_quote_position] + "\n" + "^(I'm a bot and this action was performed automatically)" + "\n" + "\n" + "^(Feedback? Bugs? )[^(Contact the developer)](mailto:marcosmartinezpalermo@gmail.com)" + "\n" + "\n" "[^(Github)](https://github.com/marcosmarp/doctor-who-bot)"
  comment.reply(reply)
  return quotes[random_quote_position]

def StoreReply(comment, reply):
  amount_of_lines = 0
  with open("replies.txt", "r", encoding='utf-8') as file_object:
    for line in file_object:
      amount_of_lines += 1
    file_object.close()
  with open("replies.txt", "a", encoding='utf-8') as file_object:
    file_object.write("Reply #" + str(int(amount_of_lines/11 + 1)))
    file_object.write("\n")
    file_object.write(" Replied comment data:")
    file_object.write("\n")
    file_object.write("   Author: " + comment.author.name)
    file_object.write("\n")
    file_object.write("   Link: https://www.reddit.com" + comment.permalink)
    file_object.write("\n")
    file_object.write("   Post:")
    file_object.write("\n")
    file_object.write("     Title: " + comment.submission.title)
    file_object.write("\n")
    file_object.write("     Author: " + comment.submission.author.name)
    file_object.write("\n")
    file_object.write("     Link: https://www.reddit.com" + comment.submission.permalink)
    file_object.write("\n")
    file_object.write(" Reply data:")
    file_object.write("\n")
    file_object.write("   Replied quote: " + reply)
    file_object.write("\n")

def InformReplyOnScreen(comment, reply):
  now = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires'))
  dt_string = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
  print(dt_string + ": replied " + comment.author.name + "'s comment with: ", file=stderr)
  print("   " + reply, file=stderr)

def CheckNewPosts(posts):
  for post in posts:
    for comment in post.comments:
      if hasattr(comment, "body"):
        if "doctor" in comment.body.lower():
          if not AlreadyReplied(comment.replies):
            quote_replied = ReplyRandomQuote(comment)
            InformReplyOnScreen(comment, quote_replied)
            StoreReply(comment, quote_replied)
            sleep(600) # Until I gain karma, minimum time between comments is 10 min


def RunBot(subreddit_handler):
 CheckNewPosts(subreddit_handler.new(limit=25))
```

And, to keep it running, I'm using a TMUX session on an AWS EC2 instance, so any comment regarding that is also appreciated.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Function and variable names in Python should follow `snake_case`.

---

[PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) recommends using 4 spaces per indentation level.

---

**`LoadQuotes`**

Whenever possible you should avoid manually opening and closing files, you can let a context manager take care of that for you (which is less error-prone):

```
with open('quotes.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
  # ... everything that accesses file happens in here

# ... everything after accessing file happens here
```

In Python you can and should usually avoid this pattern of list creation:

```
some_list = []
for element in some_iterable:
    some_list.append(element)
```

List comprehensions offer a readable and fast way of achieving the same result:

```
some_list = [element for element in some_iterable]
```

Even better, if you don't check or modify the elements, you can simply pass the iterable to the `list` constructor:

```
some_list = list(some_iterable)
```

In case of reading a file I would recommend using `readlines`:

```
def load_quotes():
    with open('quotes.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        return file.readlines()
```

---

**`AlreadyReplied`**

Using built-in `any` and a generator expression we get this really concise and readable implementation:

```
def already_replied(replies):
    return any(reply.author == "doctor-who-bot" for reply in replies)
```

`any` basically checks if an iterable contains at least one element that is `True` or [truthy](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/truthy-and-falsy-values-in-python/). The iterable we are passing to the function is a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/#id14) .

---

**`GetRandomPositionOfObject` & `ReplyRandomQuote`**

The `random` module from the standard library offers the `choice` function, which covers your exact use case. So instead of

```
random_quote_position = GetRandomPositionOfObject(quotes)
reply = quotes[random_quote_position] + ...
```

you can use `choice` like this

```
random_quote = random.choice(quotes)
reply = random_quote + ...

# ...

return random_quote
```

and get rid of `GetRandomPositionOfObject` altogether.

---

**`StoreReply`**

You're already using context managers here, great! Since they take care of closing the file you do not need to call `file_object.close()` manually.

We can count the number of elements in an iterable using built-in `sum` and a generator expression:

```
number_of_elements = sum(1 for _ in some_iterable)
```

Using `_` as a variable is a convention that signals that the value of the variable is never actually used.

Note: In general we can use built-in `len` to get the length of an iterable:

```
number_of_elements = len(some_iterable)
```

However, this does not work in this case since `object of type '_io.TextIOWrapper' has no len()`. You could use it together with `readlines`: `amount_of_lines = len(file_object.readlines())`, but I'd think this is a waste of memory, since it reads and stores all lines before counting them.

So after applying these refactorings, we get

```
with open("replies.txt", "r", encoding='utf-8') as file_object:
    amount_of_lines = sum(1 for _ in file_object)
```

Instead of manual conversion `int(amount_of_lines / 11 + 1)` you can use the floor-division operator `//`, which returns an `int`: `amount_of_lines // 11 + 1`.

If your intention is to only round up `amount_of_lines / 11` you will run into a bug whenever `amount_of_lines % 11 == 0`. Instead use `math.ceil` from the standard library: `math.ceil(amount_of_lines / 11)`

To get rid of explicit string-conversion you can let f-strings conveniently handle this for you:

```
file_object.write("Reply #" + str(int(amount_of_lines / 11 + 1)))
```

becomes

```
file_object.write(f"Reply #{math.ceil(amount_of_lines / 11)}")
```

You can also use f-strings in the other calls to `file_object.write()` to avoid manual string concatenation and write variables in a readable way.

Of course, same goes for string construction in other functions.